# is there a way to click a spot on the map and gain that area?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I need to find a way to gain everything just by clicking the location.

Answer (score 3):

There is a City Takeover upgrade at level 28 which allows you to take over a single neighbourhood. It'll cost you 40500 cash. You can get another City Takeover as a reward after the STAG Party mission, or you can get that reward from the Unlockables Pack DLC.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. When you level up enough you can choose one area. Otherwise complete all the missions in the zone and buy all the shops to own the area. Good Luck!